# Is Gazebo right for my problem?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys, I was searching and did not found the answer...

I have to make a little **car robot** and make a  **world model** were it´s can run.

I just need to make it gets the commands(go right, left, front, etc) via terminal... maybe via ROS?

Can you help me?
Its Gazebo whats i'm looking for?
Some one can give a link with some tutorial for do it? or show me were I can find a link to learn and do it my self?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14952/is-gazebo-right-for-my-problem?/) by [Canato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2937/canato/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [beginner tutorial series](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b1) would probably be a good starting point. They teach you how to make a simple vehicle and control it with a pre-existing plugin.

Once you've mastered the main concepts in that tutorial, you could either write a [Gazebo plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) to control your robot, or use [ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros) to do it.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Canato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2937/canato/) on 2016-12-01**:
Thank you for the fast answer!!

I will studie it now.

When you say "use ROS" you mean I will be able to use commands via terminal, right?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-12-01**:
Yup, the linked tutorial shows how to do it ;)